# Why doesn't the foreach recognize the string array as an array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this code:

```
private readonly string[,] sSOMETHING = new string[,]
{
    {"ONE", "TWO", "THREE"},
    {"FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX"}
};

...

foreach (string[] sELSE in sSOMETHING)
{
    ...
}
```

I get an error in the foreach that it cannot convert string to string[] when it's obvious the sSOMETHING is an array. Why doesn't it recognize the string array as an array? Do foreach have problems with multidimentional arrays?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating 2D array, not the jagged array of array. Change declaration to the following:

```
private readonly string[][] sSOMETHING = new string[][]
{
    new []{"ONE", "TWO", "THREE"},
    new []{"FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX"}
};
```

Comment: ...or, iterate the "old-fashioned" way :)

Answer (score 2):

Compiler is rightly complaining. To use the `foreach` syntax you would either need to convert it to array of arrays (`string[][]`) or access it using `for` loop by getting its dimensions:

Use the below syntax to access all the elements in the multi-dimensional array as if it was flattened

```
foreach (string sELSE in sSOMETHING) {
    Console.Write(sELSE);
}
```

or use something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < sSOMETHING.GetLength(0); ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sSOMETHING.GetLength(1); ++j) {
        Console.Write(sSOMETHING[i, j]);
    }
}
```